# Перевод сайта на другой язык: отличия в подходе выбора URL

Tags: seo, локализация

Задача, сделать на сайте 2 языка. Для каждого языка будут свой адрес, свои мета теги и т.д.

В чём основные отличия решений на поддомене *en.site.com* или на основе путей *site.com/en*?

Comment: На поддомене. Берите пример с SO, и других крупных сервисов. Во всех случаях это лучшее решение.

Comment: @TotalPusher, если вас не затруднит, не могли бы вы дать более развернутый ответ, приведя аргументы в пользу такого решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше использовать поддомен

## Возможность разнести на разные сервера на уровне DNS

Если `/en/` — придется пускать трафик через балансировщик.

## Удобнее администрировать веб-север (разные конфиги)

Случай: сначала у вас одинаковые правила обработки запросов.

Со временем "языковые версии" расходятся.

Хотите воспользоваться mod_rewrite и перезаписать `/en/` на `/...?lang=en`? Рано или поздно возникнут исключения, и придется городить огород.

Удобнее будет сделать два одинаковых файла настроек (copy-paste) и управлять ими по отдельности, чем делать один с кучей правил `/en/`. Будет чище, проще для понимания и удобно делать `diff` (смотреть отличия)

Сначала может показаться, что "copy paste" — это зло, и зачем иметь два файла настроек. [Прочитайте доклад](https://habr.com/company/oleg-bunin/blog/313666/) создателя Nginx, со слов "Правильный подход — использование copy-paste".

Для варианта `/en/`, спустя время, у вас все равно будут два "файла" настроек, пусть и в одном файле.

## robots.txt

У вас будут отдельные файлы, а не "портянка", слитая из `Disallow: /auth/`, `Disallow: /en/auth/`, `Disallow: /md/auth/`. Опять же удобство, лучшее понимание, хотя кому как.

Как по HTTP получить 2 разных файла robots.txt, находясь "внутри" одного каталога для поддоменов:

```
map $host $robots_file {
  ru.site.com robots-ru.txt;
  en.site.com robots-en.txt;
}

server {
  location = /robots.txt {
    try_files /$robots_file =404;
  }
}
```

Это часть файла настроек Nginx.

## Проще со ссылками

Вы можете делать с статьях ссылки типа `/contacts`, а не мучаться: тут `/contacts`, а тут `/en/contacts`.

Конечно, можно использовать `<base href="/en/">` и относительные ссылки... А теперь объясните это всем, кто будет размещать материалы.