# Правильная структура каталогов сайта

Tags: php, seo

Сделал информативный сайт и хотелось бы узнать - как правильно организовать структуру сайта. На моем сайте имеется информация про услуги, так же сейчас передо мной стоит задача сделать смену языка. Посоветовавшись с людьми в живую и исходя из поисков интернета, я понял, что каноном является вот такая структура:

```
app (корневая папка)  
--core  
--components  
--models  
--other code-related stuff  
--templates  
--public - именно эта папка смотрит "наружу"  
----assets  
----images  
----js  
----css  
----index.php  
--logs
```

Прочитав рекомендации гугла - ***как сделать многоязычный сайт***, я понял, что нужно создавать папки для каждого языка(ru - русский, en - английский) и в каждой папке одинаковые страницы, только на других языках. Такая структура является базой для СЕО. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, что и где разместить, исходя из текущей ситуации(смена языка)? Так же интересно в такой ситуации, где разместить файлы header.php и footer.php

Comment: Структура может быть любой - это лишь вопрос удобства. А многоязычность - смотрите в сторону роутинга и файлов локализации. Отдельно папки плодить не стоит (если станет, например, 10 языков, как поддерживать будете?)

Comment: [Лучше языки разнести на поддомены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900008/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5/900325#900325)